# Listbox item as Listbox should clear the selection of its item when other item's item is selected?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a `ListBox` as a `ListboxItem` in the mainlist. In one item that is `ListBox` I select an item. This selection should be cleared when I have another item selected from the other items `ListBox`. Code is as below:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lst" Grid.Row="3" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ItemsSource="{Binding MessageCollection}"  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Width="{Binding RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}},Path=ActualWidth}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Border  Background ="#ffffff" BorderBrush="#dddddd" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" Height="30" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:dd MMMM yyyy}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Tahoma"  Foreground="#7a7a7a" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>

                    <ListBox x:Name="lstMsgs" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  ItemsSource="{Binding MessageList}" SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedMessage,Mode=TwoWay,ElementName=me}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border x:Name="brdItem" BorderBrush="#dddddd" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" >
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush  StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#f1f1f1" Offset="0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#efefef" Offset="1"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.Background>

                                    <Grid Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  >
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Image x:Name="img" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Collapsed"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Images\icon1.png" Stretch="None" Margin="10,0,0,0"  />
                                            <TextBlock Text="Ershad Sheikh" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#2b2a2a" FontSize="12" Grid.Column="3" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupMessage}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#7a7a7a" FontSize="11"  Grid.Column="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0: hh:mm:ss tt}}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Foreground="#2378a0"  Grid.Column="7" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsReplyPresent}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="brdItem" Property="Background" Value="#e5e9eb" >                                                    
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                            <ListBox.Resources>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                     Color="#e5e9eb"/>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" 
                     Color="Transparent" />
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
                            </ListBox.Resources>
                        </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                       Color="#e5e9eb"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" 
                     Color="Transparent" />
            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: have you checked `SelectionMode`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectionmode.aspx

Comment: SelectionMode is Single only not multiple, as i need only one item to be selected and highlighted in the List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly `null` the `SelectedItem` whenever the `ListBox` loses focus, i.e you have to handle the `LostFocus` event.

You could add the event handler to the `ListBox` and handle the event in the code behind.

XAML Change:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstMsgs" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  ItemsSource="{Binding MessageList}" SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedMessage,Mode=TwoWay,ElementName=me}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" LostFocus="lstMsgs_LostFocus">
```

Code Behind:

```
    private void lstMsgs_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox listBox = sender as ListBox;
        if (listBox != null)
        {
            listBox.SelectedItem = null;
        }
    }
```

Method 2:

You could achieve the same result by using a `DependencyProperty` to handle the `LostFocus` event.

ListBoxExtension.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public static class ListBoxExtension
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty NullSelectedItemOnLostFocusProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("NullSelectedItemOnLostFocus", typeof(bool), typeof(ListBoxExtension), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnNullSelectedItemOnLostFocusChanged));

        public static bool GetNullSelectedItemOnLostFocus(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (bool)d.GetValue(NullSelectedItemOnLostFocusProperty);
        }

        public static void SetNullSelectedItemOnLostFocus(DependencyObject d, bool value)
        {
            d.SetValue(NullSelectedItemOnLostFocusProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnNullSelectedItemOnLostFocusChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool nullSelectedItemOnLostFocus = (bool)e.NewValue;

            ListBox listBox = d as ListBox;
            if (listBox != null)
            {
                if (nullSelectedItemOnLostFocus)
                    listBox.LostFocus += NullSelectedItem;
                else
                    listBox.LostFocus -= NullSelectedItem;
            }
        }

        public static void NullSelectedItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox listBox = sender as ListBox;
            if (listBox != null)
            {
                listBox.SelectedItem = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML Change 1: Add namespace in which the ListBoxExtension class is present - xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
```

XAML Change 2: Changing the `DependencyProperty` - loc:ListBoxExtension.NullSelectedItemOnLostFocus="True"

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstMsgs" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  ItemsSource="{Binding MessageList}" SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedMessage,Mode=TwoWay,ElementName=me}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" loc:ListBoxExtension.NullSelectedItemOnLostFocus="True">
```